# Combining two onEdits

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to combine multiple onEdits so that when a checkbox is true in one column, that row will shoot to a certain tab.  Likewise, when the checkbox is marked true in another, the same row will shoot to a completely different tab.

These work separately, but I am struggling extremely hard to combine.

'''

```
function onEdit(event) {
  myFunction1(event);
  myFunction2();
}

function myFunction1(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "main" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);

  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "main" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Combine");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
```

'''

Answer (score 2):

You will also need to change the sheet names.
The  biggest issue is that e.value was probably supposed to be `"TRUE"` instead of `true` that's why I checked it with the first toast command.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry' + JSON.stringify(e));
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet10" && e.value=="TRUE") {
    if(e.range.columnStart==4) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag1');
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet11");
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    }
    if(e.range.columnStart==5) {
      //e.source.toast('Flag2');
      var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet12");
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    }
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(trg)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! This is my first time posting on this site, and I am very amazed at how quickly you helped.  I will try this later for sure - just wanted to show my appreciation once I saw the response!